# Write to specific line in PHP

Tags: php

I'm writing some code and I need to write a number to a specific line. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

$statsloc = getcwd() . "/stats/stats.txt";
$handle = fopen($statsloc, 'r+');

for($linei = 0; $linei < $zone; $linei++) $line = fgets($handle);
$line = trim($line);
echo $line;

$line++;
echo $line;
```

I don't know where to continue after this. I need to write $line to that line, while maintaining all the other lines.

Comment: This statement is rather ambiguous: "I need to write $line to that line"  What are you actually trying to accomplish by "writing $line to 'that' line?"

Comment: Are you aware that the `for` loop is selecting the line numbered $zone right now and doing nothing else? If so, there are easier ways to do that.

Comment: I'm confused. I need to access that line, pull the data from it, add one to it, and then write it back. That's all I need.

Comment: Ok, but what is "that" line?  Are you referring to a particular line in stats.txt?  Are you referring to the line in stats.txt that is being processed?  (Now that I've reread it, that does seem to be the correct interpretation.)

Comment: Yes, correct - $zone is the line. I'm going to that line, grabbing the data, adding to it, and then putting that edited line back in.

Comment: You need to be specific.  What is "that." Try using specific words rather than pronouns that make it difficult for us to understand what it is you are trying to do.  For instance, say something like "I need to access a specific line in a file.  The number of that line is stored in the $zone variable" rather than simply saying "I need to access that line."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can use file to get the file as an array of lines, then change the line you need, and rewrite the whole lot back to the file.

```
<?php
$filename = getcwd() . "/stats/stats.txt";
$line_i_am_looking_for = 123;
$lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
$lines[$line_i_am_looking_for] = 'my modified line';
file_put_contents( $filename , implode( "\n", $lines ) );
```

Comment: I've assumed you need to modify a line, not inject a new one - if you need to inject a new one see deceze's answer - as for the difference between join and implode, there is none, join is an alias of implode.

Comment: I've snatched `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` from your answer, good thinking to include it. :)

Answer (score 6):

This should work. It will get rather inefficient if the file is too large though, so it depends on your situation if this is a good answer or not.

```
$stats = file('/path/to/stats', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);   // read file into array
$line = $stats[$offset];   // read line
array_splice($stats, $offset, 0, $newline);    // insert $newline at $offset
file_put_contents('/path/to/stats', join("\n", $stats));    // write to file
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this fits in with the code I already have. Can you help me out? Please?

Comment: I'm sorry, this piece is pretty self-explanatory, you'll have to give it a try yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this today and wanted to solve using the 2 answers posted but that didn't work. I had to change it to this:

```
<?php
$filepathname = "./stats.txt";
$target = "1234";
$newline = "after 1234";

$stats = file($filepathname, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);   
$offset = array_search($target,$stats) +1;
array_splice($stats, $offset, 0, $newline);   
file_put_contents($filepathname, join("\n", $stats));   
?>
```

Because these lines don't work since the arg of the array is not an index:

```
$line = $stats[$offset]; 
$lines[$line_i_am_looking_for] = 'my modified line';
```

Had to add that +1 to have the new line under the searched text.