# file_put_contents, placing content between lines

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I am practicing the file_put_contents() function, and I was wondering if this was possible.

I have a text file with the following copy:

```
--start placed content --

(content goes here)

--end placed content --
```

Is it possible to use file_put_contents to place the content inbetween the --start-- and --end-- lines. I have tried the FILE_APPEND flag, but it always places the content after the --end-- line.  Or do I need to use file_get_contents first?

Thanks a lot, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to read the whole file, process and then write the whole file back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The file needs to be read in and the data placed in the right place. You can do this with file_get_contents() to read to a string, and then use str_replace or preg_replace to replace the part between the markers with what you want, before using file_put_contents to write it back.

Answer (score 2):

You can always do:

```
$data = '--start placed content --'.PHP_EOL.$data.'--end placed content --'.PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents($file,$data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the file as an array of lines, then insert the lines where you want, and when write it all back.

Similar example on this site by nathan: [Write to specific line in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277998/write-to-specific-line-in-php)