# how to add string to a specific line of file

Tags: php

My code is:

```
<?php 

$data = file_get_contents('file.conf');
$rows = explode("\n", $data);
$rcount = count($rows); 
echo $rcount;
for ($l=0; $l<$rcount; $l++)
{
$rowss = $rows[$l];
if ($rowss == "[default]")
{
    file_put_contents($rowss, "\nhi", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX) or die("<br>oops");
}
}


?>
```

and my output is:

```
52
oops
```

and my file(file.conf) contains 52 rows that are printed successfully, but can't write on that file

I need to add some string like "hi" to the end of "[default]" line

As an example, my file is:

```
eastern=America/New_York|'vm-received' Q 'digits/at' IMp
central=America/Chicago|'vm-received' Q 'digits/at' IMp
central24=America/Chicago|'vm-received' q 'digits/at' H N 'hours'
military=Zulu|'vm-received' q 'digits/at' H N 'hours' 'phonetic/z_p'
european=Europe/Copenhagen|'vm-received' a d b 'digits/at' HM



[default]

1234 => 4242,Example Mailbox,root@localhost
;4200 => 9855,Mark Spencer,markster@linux-    support.net,mypager@digium.com,attach=no|serveremail=myaddy@digium.com|tz=central|maxmsg=        10
;4300 => 3456,Ben Rigas,ben@american-computer.net
;4310 => -5432,Sales,sales@marko.net
```

Comment: check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277998/write-to-specific-line-in-php

Comment: thank u so much Sharanya Dutta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve made two mistakes: (1) The first parameter of [`file_put_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) must be the path to the file where to write the data and (2) `FILE_APPEND` inserts data at the end – rather than in the middle – of the file; so the only thing you can do is overwrite the file entirely.

```
<?php    
$data = file_get_contents("file.conf");
$rows = explode("\n", $data);
$rcount = count($rows); 
echo $rcount;
$arr = array();
for($l = 0; $l < $rcount; $l++){
    $arr[] = $rows[$l];
    if($rows[$l] == "[default]"){
        $arr[] = "hi";
    }
}    
file_put_contents("file.conf", implode("\n", $arr), LOCK_EX) or die("<br/>oops");
?>
```

Comment: *What* have you changed? It's super hard to notice when you paste nothing but code. That said, it wouldn't help the poster. Problems should not be fixed by "here's the code fixed", but rather "your problem was X. The reason X doesn't work is because of Y. If you use method Z instead, then it would work as you want".

Comment: Sidenote: There's a function for `file_get_contents()` + `explode()`: [`file()`](http://php.net/file).

Comment: @SharanyaDutta It's bad in the way that it might discourage other people from posting, and it might also confuse op. That said, it also seems to me that it's simply to have your answer on the top and then add quality to it later, which shouldn't be done. Post a quality answer to start with and improve it. It's not much different then writing a post being `**RESERVED FOR ANSWER**` which would be awful.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, using `file` to read as array and `array_walk` to traverse the lines.

```
<?php
$data = file("file.conf"); // read to array
echo count($data) . "\n";
array_walk($data, function(&$row, $key){
    if ($row == '[default']) {
        $row .= 'SPECIAL';
    }
}) 

file_put_contents("file.conf", implode("\n", $data), LOCK_EX) 
    or trigger_error('Could not save file', E_USER_ERROR);
```