# function to write something in a specific line of a text document (php)

Tags: php, function, text-files

I have a form with two textfields:

- one asks for a *row*
- one asks for a *date*

The text which is written in the *date* field is saved into a text file. The location it is saved to is what is written into the *row* field.

Now, I require a function, which should look like this:

```
function Textwrite($filename, $string, $row)
{
    // ...
}
```

When something has already been written to a specific row, it should get overwritten.

I don't know how to implement this.

I'm a total newbie to PHP and HTML so it would be nice, if you could help me and explain it to me.

Comment: Read all the rows from the file in a loop, writing them to the new file in that same loop.  When the loop counter is equal to the row you want to overwrite, write the string value instead of what's read from the existing file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write to specific line in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277998/write-to-specific-line-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

It could look like this:

```
funtion Textwrite($filename, $string, $row) {
    $rows = file($filename);
    $rows[$row-1] = $string . "\n";
    file_put_contents($filename, implode('', $rows);
}
```